# No attribute 'BoostedTreesClassifier' error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to follow Google Cloud tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions

At the third step where you need to create and train the model:

```
# Define features
fc = tf.feature_column
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['type']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['step', 'amount', 'oldbalanceOrg', 'newbalanceOrig', 'oldbalanceDest', 'newbalanceDest']
KEY_COLUMN = 'transactionId'
def one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocab):
    return tf.feature_column.indicator_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocab))

feature_columns = []

for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    vocabulary = train_set[feature_name].unique()
    feature_columns.append(one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name,
                                           dtype=tf.float32))

# Define training and evaluation input functions
NUM_EXAMPLES = len(train_labels)
def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
    if shuffle:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    return dataset
  return input_fn

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(train_set, train_labels)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(test_set, test_labels, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1)

# Define the model
n_batches = 1
model = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(feature_columns,
                                          n_batches_per_layer=n_batches)
model = tf.contrib.estimator.forward_features(model,KEY_COLUMN)

# Train the model
model.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)

# Get metrics to evaluate the model's performance
result = model.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
print(pd.Series(result))
```

Im getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2.estimator' has no attribute 'BoostedTreesClassifier'
```

Im assuming there is something with tensorflow library, which has been updated since tutorial was written? Can anyone suggest fix for it

Comment: Maybe check out https://blog.tensorflow.org/2022/04/how-to-migrate-from-boostedtrees.html

Comment: This looks a bit overcomplicated to my needs, all i want is to call BoostedTreesClassifier correctly

Comment: I suspect you'll either have to use that approach or downgrade tensorflow to before they removed BoostedTreeClassifier (which looks like 2.7.0 - https://samanemami.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-the-boosted-tree-classifier-of-tensorflow-af2ea01a7778)

Comment: Note the warning in the version 2.6 documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.6/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier)

Comment: Then they deprecated the estimator module  in 2.9 (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf) - so you'd have to get back to 2.8.4 at least

Comment: im afraid google cloud platform does not let change version easily, always getting incompatible versions error

Comment: That's frustrating, I think you'll either have to migrate to the new version, or some other boosting algorithm.